# Trying to create entries into Database via form using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just don't know where I'm going wrong. Tried with multiple tables and was unsuccessful.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // create sql
    $catName = $_POST['category_name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Categories(c_name) VALUES($catName)";
    

    }
if($catName->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error" . $sql . "<br>" . $catName->error;
}
    
?>

<?php include ('templates/footer.php')?>
```

I get no error, but also no success. It just goes blank and no entry in the table is made.

Comment: See how to get [PHP errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). Just because you aren't seeing errors, doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: Though one thing I can tell you for sure is that running a query on a string will most certainly raise an error: `$catName->query($sql)`. You have initialized `$catName = $_POST['category_name'];`, meaning it is the string from the form. Where do you connect to your database? Also, your entire logic should be inside `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`, not just the variable initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

There are a few problems with your code...

1. You don't connect to a database
2. You're trying to use a `mysqli|pdo` method on a string (i.e. not a `mysqli|pdo`)
3. Using variables directly inside of queries is bad practice and leaves you open to SQL injection

   - Additionally, in this case, your variable appears to be a string so needs to be *in quotes* even if you were to use it directly in the query
4. Having two separate `if` statements would mean that *even if this code worked otherwise* sometimes you would run a query with not SQL statement
5. You need to enable error reporting

   - Currently you're getting a *BLANK* page because there is an *uncaught* error. If you enable error reporting then you will get a message saying what caused the issue
6. Setting `$catName` as you have could result in `Notice` messages appearing in your log file

### Solution

The key things to remember are:

1. Use *Prepared Statements* for variables
2. Enable error reporting

   - Display & log in dev environments
   - Hide & log on production

**Code**

```
// Enable error reporting in PHP; making errors output to page
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

// Database credentials:
//   You need to change these to your DB / DB User
$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'db_username';
$db_pass = 'db_password';
$db_name = 'db_name';

// Database connection
//   - Setting error reporting mode in options
$pdo = new \pdo(
    "mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);

// Initialise the variable from the form
//   ?? null   => if the variable doesn't exist then the value will be null
$catName = $_POST["category_name"] ?? null;

// Check to see if the variable exists (and isn't false)
// Warning:
//    If false equivalent values can be entered then you should
//    use a different condition (e.g. `!empty($catName)` )
if ($catName) {

    // The SQL statement with ? as a placeholder for the
    // variable we want to insert
    $sql   = "INSERT INTO categories (c_name) VALUES (?)";  

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql); // Prepare the query
    $query->execute([$catName]);  // Run the query; passing in the variable to bind

    // Ternary logic to check if "rows were inserted" and echo an appropriate
    // "success" or "failure" message
    echo $query->rowCount() ?
        "Success" :
        "Error, something went wrong!";
}
```

**Code, no comments**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user = 'db_username';
$db_pass = 'db_password';
$db_name = 'db_name';

$pdo = new \pdo(
    "mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);


$catName = $_POST["category_name"] ?? null;

if ($catName) {
    $sql   = "INSERT INTO categories (c_name) VALUES (?)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([$catName]);

    echo $query->rowCount() ?
        "Success" :
        "Error, something went wrong!";
}
```

Comment: Great, this has solved my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My main issue with this was not in the PHP, even though some of the answers above have been tremendously helpful for improving my code.

Turns out that the issue was in the form. After redoing the whole thing, it suddenly worked.

Thanks for all the answers.